# Array key as variable in foreach - PHP

Tags: php

This is probably very simple ... but I can't figure it out. I need to use array keys as variables. I have three tabs that need to use unique variables to access data.

```
$array = array(
    'items' => 'latest',
    'itemsFollow' => 'follow',
    'itemsExp' => 'expired'
);

while ( ($stuff = current($array)) !== FALSE ) {
  echo '<div id="'.key($array).'" class="tab-content grid flex">';

    foreach(/*array_key*/ as $item) { //need foreach($items, foreach($itemsFollow and foreach($itemsExp
    // do stuff
    }

  echo '</div>';

  next($array);
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $k => $v)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your array with foreach. There is no need to loop twice (nested loops) in a one dimensional array. Use `if, elseif` or `case` statements to do custom stuff depending on the value.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
     echo '<div id="'.$key.'" class="tab-content grid flex">';

     if($value=="latest"){
       //do stuff
     }
     elseif($value=="follow"){
       //do stuff
     }
     elseif($value=="expired"){
       //do stuff
     }

}
```